# Prove: $\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}\ge ab+bc+ca$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c\ge0: a+b+c=3.$ Prove that: $$\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}\ge ab+bc+ca$$

Firstly, it seems similar form to well-known result which can be proven by AM-GM: $$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\ge ab+bc+ca$$

I also tried to use AM-GM: $$ab+bc+ca\le\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}=3$$ And we need to prove that: $\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}\ge3$.

But the last one is not true. I hope someone help me to solve it. By the way, if the problem is proven, we can get a nice proof without BW method for following inequality: [nice problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4276574/prove-that-frac-sqrtaa2b2-frac-sqrtbb2c2-frac-sqrtcc/4279141#4279141)

Comment: Did you check these search results from AoPS? https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Ba%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bc%7D%5Cge%20ab%2Bbc%2Bca%24

Comment: Wow, this is the first time i seen link. It is useful to check results, thank you so much!

Comment: Have a look at [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/42969)